# How to trigger the Sonic Bomb device to shake from a third-party Android app?

Tags: android-intent, alarm, vibration, android-vibration

I recently purchased a [Sonic Bomb](https://smile.amazon.com/Vibration-Vibrating-Sleepers-Wireless-Hearing/dp/B07XJYRYTZ) vibration-based alarm device, controllable from phones.

However, there does not seem to be a public API available for controlling it.

Is there any way to trigger device shakes from third-party apps, without needing to reverse-engineer the communication protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this by finding a list of Android intents received by the [official Sonic Bomb app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonicalert.v2).

The two Android intents we're interested in: `com.sonicalert.v2.intent.test_shake`, `com.sonicalert.v2.intent.alarm_dismiss`

Usage:

```
val patterns = arrayOf(
    "!WLALALALALALALALA;", // default
    "!WTRG0TRG0TRG0TRG;", // pulse
    "!WPJ0FPV7S1J600;" // sos
    // you can add your own patterns by mixing and matching the vibration components
);

// strength is between 0 and 100; pattern follows the format seen above
fun SonicBomb_Shake(strength: Int, pattern: String, playAlarmAudio: Boolean = false) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = "com.sonicalert.v2.intent.test_shake"
    intent.putExtra("current strength m", strength)
    intent.putExtra("current pattern", pattern)
    intent.putExtra("current alarm audio", playAlarmAudio)
    MainActivity.instance!!.sendBroadcast(intent)
}
fun SonicBomb_StopShake() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = "com.sonicalert.v2.intent.alarm_dismiss"
    MainActivity.instance!!.sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

I can confirm that it works just fine. :)

Note that this does require the official app to be installed and running -- but it can be in the background, so it's not been a problem for me. (You should also be able to have your app start up the official app when it starts up, though I haven't added this yet.)

It should also be possible to reverse-engineer the official app, to figure out how to communicate with the device without needing it installed. But overall, the effort doesn't seem worth it to me given how sufficient the intent-based solution is. Also, this way you don't have to maintain the code to pair with the device and such, which is nice.